# How to copy text of a notification to the clipboard?

Tags: 18.04, budgie, notification-area, copy-and-paste

I need to copy text of a notification. It is an error message which I cannot find in any other place (log, terminal, stdout), it just shows up in the notification. I open notifications panel, select the one notification I desire and press CTRL+C. Then I tired to paste clipboard content into Sublime Text but nothing shows up. The clipboard must be empty. Same thing is with that "instant" clipboard which is available under the mouse wheel (third button).

[image: Foto of notification area in Ubuntu Budgie 18.04]

Comment: Try dragging your cursor over that area!

Comment: Do you mean by dragging - pressing LMB and moving mouse cursor to make a selection? This dragging does not help. This area is unselectable.